# View multiple fields on hover in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, report, tooltip, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am using Power BI Service Combo Chart ( column + line ) in my report. The problem is that when I hover on any data point ( may it be column or line ), it only shows the value of that particular field in my tooltip.

See images attached :

[image]

and if I add fields to "tooltip", then the  field at which im hovering gets repeated

[image]

This is how my tooltip section looks like in case 2:

[image]

How do I make the tooltip show all 3 fields when I hover on any 1 of them. It is really easy with Google Data Studio, but I don't see anything related over here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the Tooltips section on the visualizations pane.